# invalid LOC header

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to build a project in Android Studio, but it gives me this error:

```
Gradle 'MyProject' project refresh failed
Error:Cause: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
```

Other answers in SO suggest to delete corrupted jars so Gradle can download them again. My issue is that the error I have doesn't point to any jar. Furthermore, I have only the `android.jar` and `rt.jar` as jars listed in the External Libraries part of this project, and they work fine for other projects.

Is there another way to solve this issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

After trying many changes in my project, I found the answer to the issue.

When going to the build log output at `idea.log` , I found this line:

```
 Could not create an instance of Tooling API implementation using the specified Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip'.
```

I just updated `distributionurl` at `gladle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` to:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

Now the apk is built properly.